# Set opencv images/numpy array values using an array of pixels

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, array-broadcasting

Attempting to do forward warping of a homography matrix in OpenCV. You don't have to know what that means to understand the issue though.

Assume there are 2 images (an image is a 2D Numpy array of pixel values), A and B, and an array `match` that looks like

```
[[  6.96122642e+01  -1.06556338e+03   1.02251944e+00] 
 [  6.92265938e+01  -1.06334423e+03   1.02246589e+00]
 [  6.88409234e+01  -1.06112508e+03   1.02241234e+00]
 ... ]
```

The first column is X, second Y, and third is a scalar. These XY values are  image A pixel indices and correspond to the imageB indexes

```
[[0,0], 
 [0,1], 
 [0,2]
 ... ]
```

I want to use this info to quickly set imageB values from imageA. I have this working but it is not as fast as I'd like

```
yAs = np.int32(np.round( match[:, 0] / match[:, 2] )
xAs = np.int32(np.round( match[:, 1] / match[:, 2] )
it = np.nditer(pixelsImageB[0], flags=['f_index'])
while not it.finished:
    i = it.index    
    xA = xAs[i]
    yA = yAs[i] 
    if in_bounds(xA, yA, imageA):
        yB = pixB[0][i]
        xB = pixB[1][i] 
        imageB[xB,yB] = imageA[xA,yA]

    it.iternext()
```

But I'm not sure how to make this fast in Numpy, naively doing this loop is very slow. I'm a total scrub at advanced indexing, broadcasting, and the like. Any ideas?

Comment: `x` and `y` look like first candidates to move out of the loop. e.g. `x = np.int32(np.round(match[:,0] / match[:,2]))`

Comment: What's `in_bounds`?

Comment: x or y is >0 and <width, height. How would you use those x,y arrays Dan?

Comment: `in_bounds` looks like a function. Care to share the source?

Comment: `in_bounds = x >= 0 and y >=0 and x < imageA.width and y < imageA.height`

Comment: Shouldn't that be : `m = i * height + j`?

Comment: yeah something like that. Thats just pseudo code to give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be to not reinvent the wheel and use [cv.WarpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.warpPerspective) function.

Alternatively, you can use Pillow [Image.transform](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transform) method which according to docs has slight advantage over OpenCV in that it also supports bicubic interpolation, which should produce output of better quality.

Comment: Absolutely this is the best option if you actually want to get stuff done. I'm implementing it just to learn how it works and was hoping to learn a bit about Numpy here too

Comment: Ok, then 1) you move the condition (in_bounds) outside the loop by creating a mask: just replace x/y in the expression you wrote with xAs and yAs, save it into a mask variable; 2) then do the broadcasting simply like this: imageB[pixB[1, mask], pixB[0, mask]] = imageA[xAs[mask], yAs[mask]]